# How can I cache the result of a fetch call using requireJs?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I have several views which rendering result depends on the same collection and then other models or collections:

Examaples:

```
View1 -> model1, commonCollection
View2 -> collection2, commonCollection
View3 -> model3, commonCollection
```

Right now, to solve the problem I make commonCollection.fetch for each view… and before to render the page I wait that each model/collection is ready for each view
as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685673/one-view-connected-to-multiple-models/10688489#10688489).
But since the result of commonCollection is the same, I would like to cache the result for using it for other views.

How can I cache the result of commonCollection  without using global variables? I am using RequireJs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't you just override `fetch` in common collection to do the caching?

```
Backbone.Collection.extend({
   ...
   fetch: function(options) {
      if (alreadyUpdated) {
         // do nothing
      } else {
          return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.apply(this, arguments);
      }
   }
   ...
});
```

Here is a fiddle of a more complete example:
http://jsfiddle.net/4A8Wu/2/

Comment: Where/how should I define `alreadyUpdated` to have memory of this result in my commonCollection? thanks

Comment: @AntoJs I made a fiddle that'll hopefully help you out: http://jsfiddle.net/4A8Wu/2/